# Boot DOS in High Memory

Tags: boot, memory, ms-dos

I have burned a bootable disk which contains MS-DOS with the RAM drive, himem.sys. Even though, I still cannot boot it on computer with 4GB memory or more. After that, I burned a Windows 98 Live CD, still, I am not able to boot it on computer with 3.5G memory or more. it says: "Cannot fit in the memory".

My question is, what's happening in the memory? why does it say "cannot fit" when the memory is obviously large enough to fit? How should I make it bootable on these high memory computer?

Comment: Use [dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/)

Comment: Virtual box is better in my opinion.

Comment: I want to boot on a actual computer not a virtual one